# Not able to import module for a system wide install of python 3 modules

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to install python modules for all of the system users in centos. But module is not importing after a successful install

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time


def testImport():
        subprocess.call(" ".join(['sudo', 'pip-3', 'install', '--user','yaspin', 'wheel', 'netifaces']), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#   time.sleep(5)
        try:
                import yaspin
                import netifaces
                print("done")
        except Exception as e:
                print("error")
                subprocess.call(" ".join(['sudo',  'pip-3', 'uninstall', '-y', 'yaspin', 'wheel', 'netifaces']), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


def main(asd):
    testImport()


if __name__ == "__main__":
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Here is the my script.

Here is the stacktrace

```
Collecting yaspin
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/15/947df8e1cb05ec01346e7b50d167898e336417abfcb72548dbdada66f361/yaspin-0.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting netifaces
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/9b/c4c7eb09189548d45939a3d3a6b3d53979c67d124459b27a094c365c347f/netifaces-0.10.9-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: yaspin, wheel, netifaces
Successfully installed netifaces-0.10.9 wheel-0.34.2 yaspin-0.17.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 25, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./test.py", line 21, in main
    testImport()
  File "./test.py", line 12, in testImport
    import yaspin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaspin'
```

Comment: kindly add the stack trace too

Comment: @DebdutGoswami Stacktrace attaced

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I am understanding here is that, once the python script is started, it preloads the packages. So, if you are installing it inside using the script, then it might not be available in the same one.

Comment: well I am not quite sure about that but I guess you can try os.system()

Comment: Tried that as well